# Integral question help me?

Tags: integration

I am in the middle of solving a diff equation and I have  to solve $\int\dfrac{1}{\cos x}e^{\tan x}\,dx$? I am thinking about integration by parts but it is a very long way.is there another short way? Thank you :)

****Edit: The diff equation which is linear of first order that  I have to solve is (ysinx-1)dx +cosxdy=0**

**Edit again,I first find y=c*e^[-int(tgx)] then I find y' and then I replace both of them in y' +y*tgx=1/cosx..And here I have a c'=*_*___ and then I find the integral of c' which is c and finally replace it in y=c*e^[-int(tgx)].The problem is that here I have this difficult integration..**

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $\,\frac1{\cos^2x}\,$ ? It would make things really simple...

Comment: Are there any limits of integration?

Comment: No there arent limits.No it is 1/cosx.

Comment: Your question don't have an analitycal form (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28%281%2Fcos%28x%29%29*e%5E%28tg%28x%29%29%29). But DonAntonio's suggestion has (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28%281%2Fcos%5E2%28x%29%29*e%5E%28tg%28x%29%29%29)

Comment: Could it be that you messed up solving the differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

If the integral is $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{\tan(x)}}{\cos^2(x)}dx$, then there is a nice form.

Set $\tan(x) = t$. This gives us $\sec^2(x) dx = dt \implies dx = \cos^2(x) dt$. Hence, we have we then have
$$\int \sec^2(x) e^{\tan(x)}dx = \int e^t dt = e^t + \text{ constant} = e^{\tan(x)} + \text{ constant}$$

However, if the integral is $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{\tan(x)}}{\cos(x)}dx$, then there is no nice form as such, i.e.,
$$\int \sec(x) e^{\tan(x)}dx = \int \dfrac{e^t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} dt$$
which cannot be expressed via a nice elementary function.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is incorrect, so this integral never comes up.  Your ODE is,
$$
y' + y\tan x = \sec x
$$
which can be solved using an integrating factor to turn the LHS into a total derivative. This turns the ODE into,
$$
\cos x (y \sec x)' = \sec x
$$
The integration is thus $\int dx \sec^2 x$ which is just $\tan x$.  This gives $y(x)=\sin x$ which can be easily seen to solve the ODE.

Comment: No,thanks but I dont need it this way.I first find y=c*e^[-int(tgx)] then I find y' and then I replace both of them  in the ODE that you gave.And here I have a c'=______ and then I find the integral of c' which is c and finally replace it in y=c*e^[-int(tgx)].The problem is that here I have this difficult integration

Comment: Huh?  The form you suggested just gives y'=(c'/c - tanx)y which, when plugged into the ODE, yields c'/c*y=secx.  From there, I don't follow your reasoning.  Maybe you can provide some more detail of how you are solving it.  Otherwise, it's not clear at all how or why your integral appears as it certainly is not needed to solve the ODE.